# Did any Cessna Centurion ever have floats or amphibious floats?

Tags: landing-gear, amphibian, cessna-210-centurion

Most of the Cessna aircraft are also available with floats / amphibious gear. But I could find no information of a Cessna Centurion with floats or amphibious gear. Is the Centurion really not water-landing capable ?

Comment: [Found one](https://images.app.goo.gl/qJxhT7mSfUDB92jy7), but in all seriousness, the 210 in a retractable gear aircraft, the fuselage where the hard point mounts would be is probably not strong enough. Not sure about the fixed, but people say the wing is wrong?

Comment: @RonBeyer I can't see any floats on that - I mean such floats as in the other pictures below the big one.

Comment: @Programmer Ron was sarcastic, as suggested by "but in all seriousness"

Comment: Years ago C 210 was a fixed gear airplane (or at least had a fixed gear option) .  Eventually it became a retractable gear airplane and the C 206/7 airplanes (fixed gear) were made.  Lots of C206/7 airplanes are on floats.  But I have never seen a C 210 (fixed version) with floats.

Comment: @DeepSpace ah, now I see … ️

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A check of the major float manufacturer websites, [PK](https://www.pkfloats.com/), [Wipline](https://www.wipaire.com/wipline-floats/), and [Edo](http://www.kenmoreairharbor.com/models.html) (now owned by Kenmore Air Harbor) suggests that nobody ever produced a float kit and STC for the 210, so the answer is no (I'm an ex bush pilot, around airplanes since the mid 70s, and I've never heard of one).

And this makes sense because the 210 was not really optimized for float operations, mostly because its minimum flying speed is too high, with a 67 mph published stall, thanks to a fairly unforgiving highly loaded NACA 64 series laminar airfoil in the cantilever wing introduced in '67 (a scaled down version of which was used on the 68/69 Cardinal), means a take-off and landing speed in the 70s, much too fast for seaplane operations in that weight/size range (ideally, you want to be able to take off well below 60 mph to have adequate hot/heavy/glassy water performance).

For more or less the same reason, the Centurion's little sister, the Cardinal, was also never modified for floats.  The lack of lift struts on either of those models is inconvenient for float operations, but aren't technical deal breakers (bracing the Cardinal's forward cabin structure would have been quite a challenge though).

No technical reason it can't be done, even on the RG version (you're removing the gear all the same whether it's fixed or folds, and there are lots of twins like Aztecs and Beech 18s operating on floats), but no one seems to have gone to the trouble to certify a float kit for it.

Add in the fact that the airplane's 180/182/206 relatives are far more suitable, it pretty much eliminates any incentive to develop a kit for the 210.

Answer (score 2):

Let's imagine you manufacture floats for Cessna aircraft. The obvious candidates for float conversion would be those Cessnas with large engines, fixed gear and stretched fuselages. Big engines let you haul at max gross and furnish improved hot & high performance. Stretched fuses let you carry odd-shaped cargo. Fixed gear yields convenient attachment points for the float struts. Since you need a certain number of retrofits to justify your design investment, you'll choose the Cessna model that meets those criteria AND which was manufactured in the greatest numbers.

What all this adds up to is you'll pick a 250 HP Cessna with 6 seats and fixed gear and ignore anything that was built out in relatively small numbers. And: you'll ignore retractables because *their use model doesn't match your target market.*